# Trying to create a function that sorts rows of 2D array using bubble sort and then prints it

Tags: c, arrays

I am trying to sort a 2D array using bubble sort and then print the newly sorted array. This is what I have so far:

```
void sort_2Darray(int x[][MAX],int size)
{
  int i;
  int j;
  int hold;
  int pass;

  for(pass=1;pass<size;pass++)
  {
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<size;j++)
      {
        if(x[i][j]>x[i][j+1])
        {
          hold=x[i][j];
          x[i][j]=x[i][j+1];
          x[i]j+1]=hold;
        }
      }
    }
    for(i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
      for(j=0;j<size;j++)
      { 
        printf("%2d", x[i][j]);
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
}
```

And this is what it prints when size==4

before sorting:

```
0 3 6 6
2 9 7 0
4 1 1 1 
7 0 2 6
```

after it printed this 4 times:

```
0 3 6 6
2 7 0 0
1 1 1 4
0 2 6 -352439155
```

Comment: What's the problem? What is expected?

Comment: Is there a question somewhere here?

Comment: When `j` is equal to `size - 1`, what do you think the index `j + 1` is going to be?

Comment: I changed the code so that the printing is done outside of the first for statement,so it prints a sorted array, but there is no real manner in which it is sorted by. So the question is, is there something wrong with how I set up the bubble sort?

Comment: @Matt  The original array is already sorted by rows.:) How are you going to sort the array?

Comment: @Matt there is already a comment-answer from Joachim Pileborg. The first `j` loop `for(j=0;j<size;j++)` should be `for(j=0;j<size-1;j++)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for(pass=0;pass<size;pass++)
{
  for(i=0;i<(size-1);i++)
  {
    for(j=0;j<(size-i-1);j++)
    {
      if(x[pass][j]>x[pass][j+1])
      {
        hold=x[pass][j];
        x[pass][j]=x[pass][j+1];
        x[pass][j+1]=hold;
      }
    }
  }
```

I haven't tested this code, but this should work properly and do the job, I think.

Please report if it doesn't work.